# Mongoose return average of values grouped by fields in subdocument

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a kind of yelp clone using express/mongoose and need to be able to return an object containing the average score for each of the rating categories (for ex: global, location, food, and ambience), each from a different review subdocument. A sample Restaurant would look something like this (I've taken out irrelevant fields):

```
{ 
  name: 'Test Restaurant',
  reviews: [ 
    { 
      _id: 5e42c12e903eac188077dca5, 
      rating: {
        global: 10,
        location: 5,
        food: 8,
        ambient: 6
        } 
    },
    { 
      _id: 5e42c12e903eac188077dca6, 
      rating: {
        global: 5,
        location: 6,
        food: 4,
        ambient: 2
        } 
    },
    { 
      _id: 5e42c12e903eac188077dca7, 
      rating: {
        global: 9,
        location: 3,
        food: 5,
        ambient: 1
        } 
    },
  ]
}
```

So far I've been able to do this using the following virtual, but I imagine this rapidly becoming inefficient if the number of reviews grows big enough:

```
restaurantSchema.virtual("averageRatings").get(function() {
  const restaurant = this;
  const ratings = restaurant.reviews.map(review => review.rating);
  const ratingsArrays = {};
  const averageRatings = {};
  const categories = [
    "global",
    "food",
    "ambient",
    "location"
  ];

  //Loop for every category, create new array with the ratings from each review per category, and filter out null ratings
  categories.forEach(category => {
    ratingsArrays[category] = ratings
      .map(rating => rating[category])
      .filter(value => value != null);

  //Calculate average for each category, and return undefined where there are not ratings
    averageRatings[category] =
      ratingsArrays[category].reduce((acc, current) => acc + current, 0) /
        ratingsArrays[category].length || undefined;
  });
  return averageRatings;
});
```

Now, I've seen the more efficient/proper way of doing this is by using the MongoDB aggregation framework, but even though I've looked through the manual and found some very good answers for particular situations, I haven't been able to work through it in this particular case.

Could help me with an approximate pipeline I could work with? Do you know of any resources to learn MongoDB query/aggregation syntax in a friendlier way than the official manuals (Something like this for SQL: https://sqlbolt.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Aggregation Framework you can calculate your averages dynamically reading `rating` keys. Try to start with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and then group by retrieved keys (`k`). Ultimately you need to run reverse operation which is [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$reviews"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            values: { $objectToArray: "$reviews.rating" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$values"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { _id: "$_id", k: "$values.k" },
            sum: { $sum: "$values.v" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            averages: { $push: { k: "$_id.k", v: { $divide: [ "$sum", "$count" ] } } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            avgReviews: { $arrayToObject: "$averages" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eeEX2IzEp0c)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Are there any resources you'd recommend to learn this stuff? (other than the official manuals...)

Comment: @Dijkie85 I believe the official documentation has really good quality - lot of examples etc. You just need to browse all the stages and operators to get yourself familiar with the capabilities of AF.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @mickl, but if it's not too difficult for a comment, could you point me to the way to return this aggregation as part as the restaurant object (ie., not just the aggregation by itself), alongside its other properties?. Sorry for this spoon feed session; I've got lots to learn...

Comment: @Dijkie85 here's how to do that for `name`: https://mongoplayground.net/p/25HlCkh1nR- , - you can follow the same approach for other fields

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you again. To be sure, will this work as well  for a collection of restaurants too?

Comment: @Dijkie85 yes, it should :-)

Comment: I followed the approach you suggested for `name` (here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VG73n5oa9qr) and got to display everything ok, except the `reviews`, which should be an array, but it's only returning the first (although the average calculations are done correctly). I tried removing the `$first` operator, but then it throws an error because (I think) an array cannot work as an acummulator... Any pointers? :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Dijkie85 `$push` instead of `$first` for an array: https://mongoplayground.net/p/P0MP3gwCFFe

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks!